# Sort sentences in list in order of text

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have extracted some sentences from a text in Python. The text is stored in a string and the sentences in a list. Here's some sample input:

```
text = "This is a text. This is sentence 1. Here is sentence 2. And this is sentence 3."
extracted = ['Here is sentence 2.', 'This is a text']
```

Now I would like to order the elements from the list `extracted` according to their chronology in the text. This is my desired output:

```
ordered_result = ['This is a text', 'Here is sentence 2.']
```

Does anybody has an idea how to do so?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? We're keen to help you but only if you've shown some effort first. SO isn't here to implement this for you.

Comment: The trivial solution is to calculate the index of each sentence (substring) in the string, and sort keyed on that. However, it's not going to be optimal performance-wise, since you worst-case scan full text for each substring.

Comment: The obvious solution is to build the `extracted` list in such a way that it's already ordered...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Straightforwardly sort them by the position in the original string:

```
ordered_result = sorted(extracted, key=lambda x: text.index(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a dictionary to construct an index mapping with O(n) complexity.

Then use `sorted` with a custom key, utilizing this dictionary.

This method relies on having a list of sentences to begin with. I've constructed one below in case you don't have this available.

```
text = "This is a text. This is sentence 1. Here is sentence 2. And this is sentence 3."

extracted = ['Here is sentence 2.', 'This is a text.']

# create list of sentences
full_list = [i.strip()+'.' for i in filter(None, text.split('.'))]

# map sentences to integer location
d_map = {v: k for k, v in enumerate(full_list)}

# sort by calculated location mapping
extracted_sorted = sorted(extracted, key=d_map.get)

['This is a text.', 'Here is sentence 2.']
```

Answer (score 0):

The preferred (but slightly more complex) way to do this is to use a regex search:

```
import re

expression = re.compile(r'([A-Z][^\.!?]*[\.!?])')
text = "This is a text. This is sentence 1. Here is sentence 2. And this is sentence 3."

# Find all occurences of `expression` in `text`
match = re.findall(expression, text)

print match
# ['This is a text.', 'This is sentence 1.', 'Here is sentence 2.', 'And this is sentence 3.']
```

The trivial (but simpler) way to do this is to split it on `". "` and then you have your list of sentences, in chronological order. The only downside to this is you lose the punctuation.

```
text = "This is a text. This is sentence 1. Here is sentence 2. And this is sentence 3."
splitt = text.split(". ")

print splitt
# splitt = ['This is a text', 'This is sentence 1', 'Here is sentence 2', 'And this is sentence 3.']
```